# Primefaces select another page to avoid reset value in inputTextbox

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces 6.0.My Scenario is - InputText's inside the dataTable in which each page contain's 5 rows. In page 1 I have edited the value in a inputText and if I use paginator to scroll from page 1 to page 2 again come back to page 1 the inputText reset to it's old value.I haven't use p:ajax page event.
My doubt is scroll event perform to show the current value in the textbox?